# Replacing argument in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a base class I cannot modify (code may have other errors, but please ignore those)

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        self.parser.add_argument("arg1", choices=("a", "b"))
```

What I want is to override arg1 as follows

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.parser.add_argument("arg1", choices=("a", "c", "d"))
```

Comment: what's wrong with this code? it works for me. Your argument just gets overwritten.

Comment: @MrE ```$ python subclass.py c
usage: subclass.py [-h] {a,b} {a,b,c}
subclass.py: error: argument arg1: invalid choice: 'c' (choose from 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: This code defines 2 positional arguments, each with a different choices set.

Comment: Talk about closing the barn door after the horses escaped!  Did anyone who voted to close read the answers?

Comment: I doubt it. I don't even think they read the question. It was not a debugging help to begin with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can't modify the base class implementation, you *could* reach into the attributes of the `parser` and modify the specific action you care about.  Here's a sketch of code demonstrating just that:

```
from base import BaseClass


def _modify_choices(parser, dest, choices):
    for action in parser._actions:
        if action.dest == dest:
            action.choices = choices
            return
    else:
        raise AssertionError('argument {} not found'.format(dest))


class MySubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySubClass, self).__init__()
        _modify_choices(self.parser, 'arg1', ('a', 'b', 'c'))


def main():
    inst = MySubClass()
    inst.parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

And usage:

```
$ python subclass.py d
usage: subclass.py [-h] {a,b,c}
subclass.py: error: argument arg1: invalid choice: 'd' (choose from 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Note that this reaches into private implementation details (notably `ArgumentParser._actions`) but otherwise uses public interfaces.

Comment: I'd probably `def _append_choice` with  `action.choices = action.choices + appended_choices` with `('c',)` in case the base class does change you don't overwrite those changes, but it's a trade off. Either way, we're betraying the inheritance from `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 2):

`add_argument` creates an `Action` object that encodes the parameters give in the `add_argument` call.  Those can be read and/or modified after creation.

```
class BaseClass(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        self.arg = self.parser.add_argument("arg1", choices=("a", "b"))
        # self.arg is now the Action object defined by this add_argument method

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        # modify the choices attribute of self.arg
        self.arg.choices = ("a","b","c")
```

That Action object can also be found in the `parser._actions` list, but I prefer to save a reference in my own code.

(this code hasn't been tested, so might have an error or two.)

---

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="BASE")
        self.parser.add_argument("arg1", choices=("a", "b"))
        self.parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.parser.prog = "DERIVED"
        print(self.parser._actions)
```

shows this list when a DerivedClass is created:

```
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None), 
 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='arg1', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=('a', 'b'), help=None, metavar=None), 
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

So adding:

```
    idx = [a.dest for a in self.parser._actions].index('arg1')
    self.parser._actions[idx].choices = ("a","b","c")

p1 = BaseClass()
p1.parser.print_help()

p2 = DerivedClass()
p2.parser.print_help()
```

produces 2 usages:

```
usage: BASE [-h] [-f FOO] {a,b}

positional arguments:
  {a,b}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

and

```
usage: DERIVED [-h] [-f FOO] {a,b,c}

positional arguments:
  {a,b,c}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

Comment: "I have a base class I cannot modify" I'm not sure how this satisfies that constraint.

Comment: If you can't fiddle with the base class then I'd look for the Action in the `_actions` list.

Comment: How would I get the right action from the _actions list? I can't get it by the index, since that could change (the base class author may add more)

Comment: @max_max_mir, if you can't pick one, such as the last, then searching by `dest` as given in the other answer is probably the way to go.

Comment: @max_max_mir, you could search in like manner on any of the attributes,including the `choices`.